# Why are business visitors hidden in the Quantcast statistics?

Tags: support, statistics

I'm curious as to why all of the [stats](http://www.quantcast.com/stackoverflow.com), except business visitors, are open and visible. Is there a reason for this?

Comment: Might as well get a little bell and shake it when you want Jeff's attention. Make sure to give him some food pellets if he's a good boy.

Comment: I find the best way to get his attention is to tag things boat-programming

Comment: don't know, I didn't do it -- sent email to Joel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joel said he didn't set this, so it must be a default at Quantcast. He said he'd look at at and see if there's an easy way to make it visible (the whole point of Quantcast is public visibility..), but the Quantcast UI is not so great.

Comment: I think I turned it on, although the Quantcast UI is horrible (the link to turn it on doesn't provide any feedback whatsoever, but I still think it did something). You might have to be logged onto Quantcast to see it.

Comment: I just tried to access business details for UX.stackexchange.com but it's giving me the "this stuff is hidden" message. Did it break again or has it never worked? Or do you need to configure it per site?

Answer (score 1):

**Two reasons for exposing your stats**

- let your potential advertisers (especially the help wanted ones) see how many people they're going to reach.
- Get some additional buzz from people noticing the site's impressive growth.

Basically you can ask yourself the question, "would the site be better / more interesting / more profitable if this information was hidden?"